# Classes from Paypal's adaptive payments SDK won't load on my server

Tags: php, paypal

I have question about implementing Paypal's Adaptive Payments on my website. I'm trying to follow the steps in this [link](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/php?env=sandbox).

Step 1 obviously works, but for step 2 I need to install the SDK. I did this, using the non-composer install (basically I downloaded the zip, extracted it on my server, and required the autoload.php script in the page where the button from step 1 links to). However, it tells me "class not found" when I try to run the script from step 2. I tried several classes, but it's unable to use any of them.

Is this because I didn't use composer for the installation? If so, how do I use composer to install something on a server? The website is hosted by inmotionhosting, I'm not running this on a local apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to update your PHP version on your server.  The namespacing that the autoloader uses was introduced in PHP 5.3.  If you're using anything prior to that you'll end up with class not found errors.

Comment: I guess you just need to make sure the file paths for everything related to the autoload file are correct.

Comment: Another option would be to use this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead.  It's a lot easier to work with than PayPal's.  Even their own integration people prefer it.